# MATLAB - Trouble of converting training data to spectrogram

Tags: signal-processing, fft, dct, spectrogram

I am a student and new to signal processing just few months ago. I picked  "A Novel Fuzzy Approach to Speech Recognition" for my project (you can google for the downloadable version).

I am a little stuck in converting the training data into a spectrogram which has been passed through a mel-filter.

I use [this](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/melbankm.html) for my mel-filterbank, with a little modification of course.

Then I wrote this simple code to make the spectrogram of my training data:

```
p   =25;
fl  =0.0;
fh  =0.5;
w   ='hty';
[a,fs]=wavread('a.wav'); %you can simply record a sound and name it a.wav, other param will follows
n=length(a)+1;
fa=rfft(a);
xa=melbank_me(p,n,fs); %the mel-filterbank function
za=log(xa*abs(fa).^2);
ca=dct(za);
spectrogram(ca(:,1))
```

All I got is just like this which is not like the paper say::

[image]

Please let me know that either my code or the spectrogram I have was right. if so, what do I have to do to make my spectrogram like the paper's? and if didn't, please tell me where's the wrong

And another question, is it ok to having the lenght of FFT that much?
Because when I try to lower it, my code gives errors.

Comment: Why are you taking the spectrogram of the mfcc coeffs? The last step of calculating the mffc's is taking the dct. What are you trying to achieve with the spectrogram function?

Comment: actually, I don't mean to take the mfcc code as spectrogram, what I want to do is to take the spectrogram of my voice sample after it passed mel-filterbank, is my code wrong?

I have dct'd it.

I'm trying to make my sample voice as a template, so I can make the fuzzification rule based on the template I

Comment: actually, I don't mean to take the mfcc code as spectrogram, what I want to do is to take the spectrogram of my voice sample after it passed mel-filterbank, is my code wrong?

I have dct'd it.

I'm trying to make my sample voice as a template, so I can make the fuzzification rule based on the template I've made. just like the paper. that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing an FFT of the entire file - that will include too much time-varing information - you should pick a window size in which the sound is relatively stationary, e.g. 10 ms @ 44.1 kHz = 441 samples, so perhaps N = 512 might be a good starting point. You can then generate your spectrogram over successive windows if needed, in order to display the time-varying frequency content.

Comment: thank you, I'll try for that.
then, can you explain me about my spectrogram picture?
i mean, is my picture generated by my code is right?
if so,how should I do for the further process so I can make it like the paper say?
and if don't, where is the wrong?

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper ?

Comment: [from ieee](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1410027)
[downloadable ver](http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.cs.tum.edu%2F~ziaie%2Ffiles%2Fscientific_papers%2FA%2520Novel%2520Fuzzy%2520Approach%2520to%2520Speech%2520Recognition.pdf&ei=U0N4TvvSNILprAeuseCNCw&usg=AFQjCNG42mmqTG_EY4Vqb5T92Z_4sgQP_w&sig2=qmebyhPmrJ3VyrbJCou6bQ)

Comment: Your spectrogram is rotated 90 degrees and has very little resolution on the time axis because you have FFT'd the whole file, as mentioned above. If you use a sliding window of a reasonable size (e.g. N = 512 or 1024) then you will get much more resolution in the time axis. You should probably also apply a window function prior to the FFT (e.g. Hann window) to get rid of spectral leakage.

Comment: one simply last question, after I rotate it 90 degrees, is it same as the paper's?

thank you for your kindness

Comment: Yes, it should be similar - you can test it with some simple input signals to make sure it works correctly, e.g. sine waves at different frequencies/amplitudes.